# CI/CD using github action django project Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, github-actions, cicd

following is my yaml file that I am using the project is running just fine when i run it from vscode but when i push it to git the code fails saying the venv is might not be active but the requirements file installs successfull the exact error is as follows

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

```
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Create Dependencies List
      run: |
        pip freeze > requirements.txt
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Activate venv
      run: |
        source .venv/Scripts/activate.bat
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        python manage.py test"
```

Comment: 1) Github Actions runs Linux containers, so `acitvate.bat` is the wrong file to source. Or you could not source it, and just run `.venv/bin/python manage.py test` 2) You need to source the venv before running pip 3) You also should commit your requirements.txt file and not overwrite it everytime the action runs

Comment: You're freezing the requirements only to reinstall them, which isn't right. Something tells me you've misread a tutorial, the requirements need to be frozen before the workflow runs

Comment: so without the freeze comand git cant seem to locate the requirements.txt file and the same thing is happening with the manage,py file even though they are all in there correct location. also as for the following command there is no bin in the venv  .venv/bin/python manage.py test so this fails as well  @OneCricketeer

Comment: If it cannot locate the requirements, then it's being ignored by git, or it was never committed, which it should be. And there doesn't need to be a bin folder, I'm just saying that you can directly invoke the Python (Linux) executable without sourcing the environment. Otherwise, you need to source the correct **non-windows** activate file

Comment: Resolved what helped was debugging with PWD ; LS ;